# Gin binding middleware always fail

Tags: go, binding, middleware, go-gin

Im trying to have custom error messages for gin validation & followed the advice in this thread: https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/430

Im trying the gin binding midddleware this way:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type itemPostRequest struct {
    Name string `json:"name" binding:"required"`
}

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.Use(func (c *gin.Context) {
        c.Next()
        fmt.Println(c.Errors)
    })
    router.POST("/item", gin.Bind(itemPostRequest{}), func (c *gin.Context) {
        fmt.Println("Im inside handler")
        req := c.MustGet(gin.BindKey).(*itemPostRequest)
        fmt.Println(req)
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"success": true})
    })
    router.Run()
}
```

I send the request using Postman but although I have sent the correct request, it always say:
Key: 'itemPostRequest.Name' Error:Field validation for 'Name' failed on the 'required' tag

If I don't use the binding middleware:

```
router.POST("/item", func (c *gin.Context) {
  ...
```

It works but i want to be able to bind and return error before I go to the handler, just like the advice on the thread. Why is this not working? Thank you

Comment: The error message is indicating that the request is incorrect.  It would be helpful to include an example request (both headers and body) that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx to the comment, I realized I missed Content-Type application/json. I didn't realize this because I used c.ShouldBindWithJSON before and it didnt need this header.